# input_file_name not working in spark-xml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to add input file name for every row when loading xml file through `com.databricks.spark.xml` format. But it is returning empty column for filename..

Here is the code snippet. I'm using `input_file_name` function:

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "BO_RECORD")
  .load("file:///<path>/*")
  .withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
  .show()
```

Which returns:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
|TicketRefund|TicketsSold|_corrupt_record|filename|
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
|           0|          3|           null|        |
|           0|          1|           null|        |
|           0|         18|           null|        |
|           0|         22|           null|        |
|           0|          3|           null|        |
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

I tried with different ways, but still it returns empty filename when using com.databricks.spark.xml.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "BO_RECORD")
  .load("file:///<path>/*")
  .select(input_file_name())
  .show()
```

However it works good when doing a normal data-frame load for text files.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
... .withColumn("filename",lit("anyFileName")). ..
```

If it will not work, check is function "input_file_name()" worked fine in all executors, not only driver node.

Comment: Hi, Kindly check my question. Its about input_file_name() not working in spark-xml processing

Comment: sorry, in initial message function package was not mentioned.